Does the game track the "type" of a non-permadeath game slot after the Waypoint update? Do I miss anything by going from Survival to Custom?
Before the Waypoint update, players could select one of the following difficulty settings when starting a new game:

creative - infinite resources, no death, etc
normal - default setting
survival - a little harder than normal (increased costs, less resources etc)
permadeath - save slot is deleted on death

The Waypoint update introduced the ability to further customize these settings, both at the start of a new save slot or later.
While obviously "Permadeath" is still a special case (I don't think you can disable or enable it at a latter time since completing the game in permadeath gives an achievement) I was wondering if the game still tracks you current mode for any other purpose.
While playing ins Survival, the max size of any item stack is greatly reduced. While the intended reason for this was probably to make player have less stocked up resources as soon as you get the freighter mater teleport upgrade all you are left with is just ... lot of lost time to micromanage stacks in a not-so-great UI.
If that is not enough, even large refiners get a 250 runaway mold stack limit (despite the inventory stack limit being 500), and having to refine the like of 30-40k mold you just got from a farm by running around your refiners and refilling them every 40-50 seconds make for a really really really boring game-play (also worth noticing that without abusing bugs a planet base is limited to the like of TWO large refiners, yet freighter bases seems unrestricted).
For these reasons I was considering changing the stack item limit setting on my save slot and start living again without needing to constantly micromanaging stuff that I am well past the point to care (by now, with S rank capital ship, weapons in the 100k dmg range, fully upgraded suit and so on it is not like resources are a constraint anymore, the only important thing is nanite and all the limit is doing is making the refinement more tedious). Yet, since I can do this only once (you can increase stack size but you can't reduce it) I was going over the possible hidden issues.
For this reason I am wondering if the game is somehow tracking that the save slot is a "survival" rule slot and if I am at risk of missing anything by converting to a "custom" slot (if the game even differentiates non-permadeath game modes).

UPDATE: apparently the stack size limits are even more idiotic on the "harsh setting". In that case some refiner recipes become straight UNUSABLE because your stack limit is smaller than the required resource amount.


For what I remember, yes, the game tracks your save type. For example, when looking at other players' bases, you can see a different icon under the base's name depending on the game difficulty
